# Woocommerce - Automatically populate category for products with only 1 unit left in Stock

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have been using the following code to automatically generate a category for all products that are on sale. It works as expected

```
/**
 * @snippet       Automatically Populate Sale Product Category
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 6
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'bbloomer_sale_category' );
 
function bbloomer_sale_category( $q ) {
   if ( "sale" !== $q->get( 'product_cat' ) ) return; // "sale" = slug
   $q->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
   $q->set( 'product_cat', null );
   $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() ? wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() : array();
   $q->set( 'post__in', $product_ids_on_sale );
}
```

What I would like to do is automatically generate a category for products that only have one item left in stock.

Also possibly generate a category for sale products with only 1 item left in stock.  Sort of a last chance sale category.

Any suggestions on how I could modify the above ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello from Business Bloomer himself :)

If you look at the docs for "[wc_get_products](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)", there is a way to get products based on their stock quantity:

```
$args = array(
    'stock_quantity' => 1,
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

Let's also make sure products are published, visible, and that we return product IDs:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'stock_quantity' => 1,
    'visibility' => 'catalog',
    'limit' => -1,
    'return' => 'ids',
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

Now you can use this inside your (my) function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'bbloomer_sale_category' );
 
function bbloomer_sale_category( $q ) {
   if ( "sale" !== $q->get( 'product_cat' ) ) return; // "sale" = slug
   $q->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
   $q->set( 'product_cat', null );
   $args = array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'stock_quantity' => 1,
    'visibility' => 'catalog',
    'limit' => -1,
    'return' => 'ids',
   );
   $products = wc_get_products( $args );
   $q->set( 'post__in', $products );
}
```

As you mentioned, if you wanted to get products with 1 in stock AND on sale, simply find the intersection of the two arrays:

```
function bbloomer_sale_category( $q ) {
    if ( "sale" !== $q->get( 'product_cat' ) ) return; // "sale" = slug
    $q->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
    $q->set( 'product_cat', null );
    $args = array(
     'status' => 'publish',
     'stock_quantity' => 1,
     'visibility' => 'catalog',
     'limit' => -1,
     'return' => 'ids',
    );
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );
    $products_stock_1_on_sale = array_intersect( $products, wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() ); 
    $q->set( 'post__in', $products_stock_1_on_sale );
 }
```

Untested, but it should work. Let me know

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I tried your code and it worked as expected mostly ... I found it did not display all the products I had with a stock qty of 1.  After some trial and error I found that if I edited the products quantity to another value saved it, and then edited it back to 1 and saved it, it would then show as expected.  It's almost like there is some sort of time component involved.  It's almost like it only works with products whose qty changed to 1 after a certain date (today?).   Further testing showed that products that sold down to a qty of 1 displayed as expected.

Comment: Cool. It could be a problem with cache / transients by the way, so maybe run some "Tools" from the WooCommerce Status > Tools section and see if that resets it